# Scraping change price of stocks in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to **scrape** the change price of some stocks.

I tried this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL&.tsrc=fin-srch').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
ChangePrice = soup.find('span', {'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($positiveColor)'}).text
print(ChangePrice)
```

Output: `+1.59 (+0.36%)`

.

As u can see at the end of `ChangePrice` variable it is **$positiveColor**, my problem is when I put a losing stock I have to change this to **$negativeColor** to make it work fine, is there any solution to make it works with both stocks the Positive color and the Negative color without changing code every time?

.

I tried to remove `C($positiveColor)` but it gives me an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`
.

I wish my problem is clear, if anyone can help me I will be so appreciated.

.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add both `classes` in a `list` to select either one.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL&.tsrc=fin-srch').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
ChangePrice = soup.find('span', {'class': ['Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($positiveColor)',
                                           'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($negativeColor)']}).text

print(ChangePrice)
```